# OpenMesh geometric vector operations

Tags: openmesh

OpenMesh has its [VectorT class](https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de/media/openmesh_static/Documentations/OpenMesh-Doc-Latest/a02001.html) which I believe is used to carry out all sorts of position vector operations (additions/subtractions, inner and outer products, etc.). Are there any examples available on how to actually use it? I would be in particular interested in

1. How to define and initialize a 3D vector of coordinates
2. How to properly convert a vertex position (of Point type) to a VectorT type, or, alternatively, how to get a vertex position as a VectorT type right away. So far I'm using `mesh.point(vhandle)` which, however, returns a `Point()` type.

**Edit:** Apparently `Point` is some kind of `VectorT` itself because the `VectorT` member functions work on `Point` objects as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples for math operation using OpenMesh native point type:

1. `OpenMesh::Vec3f myVec = OpenMesh::Vec3f(0, 0, 0);`
2. `float distance = (point1 - point2).norm();`
   also available: `l1_norm()`, `l8_norm()`, `sqrnorm()`
3. `Point interpolated_point = (1 - a) * point1 + a * point2;`
4. `Vec3f crossProduct = vec1 % vec2;` only defined for `Vec3` (and as you mentioned `Point`)
5. `Vec3f dotProduct = vec1 | vec2;`